# Steps for uploading react app crated by create-react-app on goDaddy hosting

Tags: reactjs, hosting

I bought a hosting on goDaddy for my React application, but unfortunately I cannot uploaded my App as I don't which files and where to put them in cPanel file's manager on goDaddy. Can someone help my with this, by reproducing the steps for that procedure?

Comment: Follow this [link](https://github.com/ShaneMckenna23/react-help/tree/react-hosting)

Moreover react has nothing to do with goDaddy. It just provides a domain name.

Comment: it does not matter where you bought the domain, you should host/deploy your app somewhere then define your domain there. for instance Firebase hosting https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Comment: No, I have bought also a hosting on goDaddy, not only a domain name.

Comment: did you deploy it ? I am having a problem too !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask godaddy support for help to host your site. All the site contents are in your build folder after running `yarn build` (if you used create-react-app).

Now, having said that, If you want to quickly host your site, no hassle and by just dragging and dropping your site into a tool that automatically deploys it for you, check: https://www.netlify.com/

You can use it for free, and re-use the domain you bought in godaddy.

Answer (score -1):

**Follow below steps:**

1. Build your react project

   `npm run build`
2. You should have a domain and a web hosting plan. Open the cPanel if you purchased a hosting plan from GoDaddy.
3. Convert the build folder to a zip file, upload the zip file to the `public_html` folder, and then unzip the file. Move the files from the "build" folder one level up.

This medium article might be helpful for you: [click here](https://medium.com/@mankum8798/embark-on-a-digital-odyssey-deploy-your-react-app-on-godaddys-cosmic-domain-1e3c09dbf8a0)